# wheels dont move at the same speed

Tags: ros2, pid, ros-humble, wheeled-robot, gazebo-11

I'm working with ROS2 Humble and Gazebo 11. I'm doing a 4 wheel robot with Ackermann steering using the gazebo_plugins_Ackermann. The thing is I copy the example of Gazebo for this kind of car from: /opt/ros/humble/share/gazebo_plugins/worlds file: gazebo_ros_ackermann.

I've changed some parameters such as link mass, inertias, PID values... for my robot but I can get the rear wheel, which propulse the robot,to turn at the same speed as the front ones. I mean, I modificated the frictions parameters of the front wheel close to zero in order to give freedom movement on the x axis. But when I launch the simulation the rear wheel spin and the front wheels seem to be slowed down and I don't know why. I don't understand why the front wheels don't move as the rear wheel f they don't have friction.

Theoretically the coefficient of friction depends only on the characteristics of the materials so they are the same as the Prius car from Gazebo.

My code here in sdf format:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<model name="robot_exteriores">
  <pose>0 0 0.03 0 0 0</pose>
  <link name="chassis">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 1.57</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>4</mass>
      <pose>0.02002 0 0.007595 0 0 0</pose>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>1.8922e-2</ixx>
        <ixy>0.0</ixy>
        <iyy>1.27806e-1</iyy>
        <ixz>0</ixz>
        <iyz>0.0</iyz>
        <izz>1.44868e-1</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>

    <visual name="chassis_visual">
    <pose>0 0 0 1.57 0 3.14159265</pose>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://robot_desc/meshes/base_link.stl</uri>
          <scale>0.001 0.001 0.001</scale>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision name="chassis">
      <pose>0.0 0.0 0.03 0 0 1.5708</pose>
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>0.70 0.270 0.08</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <link name="steering_wheel">
    <pose>0.2 0 0.1 -1.302101 0 1.57</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>1.0</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>0.14583300</ixx>
        <ixy>0</ixy>
        <ixz>0</ixz>
        <iyy>0.14583300</iyy>
        <iyz>0</iyz>
        <izz>0.12500000</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>
    <collision name="collision">
      <geometry>
        <cylinder>
          <radius>0.01</radius>
          <length>0.004</length>
        </cylinder>
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <contact>
          <ode>
            <min_depth>0.003</min_depth>
          </ode>
        </contact>
      </surface>
    </collision>
    <visual name="visual">
      <pose>0 0 0 1.302101 0 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://prius_hybrid/meshes/Hybrid.obj</uri>
          <scale>0.001 0.001 0.001</scale>
          <submesh>
            <name>Steering_Wheel</name>
            <center>true</center>
          </submesh>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <link name="torre">
    <pose>0 0 0 0 0 1.5707963267948966</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>1.5</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>0.01</ixx>
        <ixy>0</ixy>
        <ixz>0</ixz>
        <iyy>0.01</iyy>
        <iyz>0</iyz>
        <izz>0.01</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>

    <visual name="visual">
      <pose>0.0 0.0 0.0 0 0 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://robot_desc/meshes/torre_lidar.stl</uri>
          <scale>0.001 0.001 0.001</scale>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision name="collision">
      <pose>0 0.019 0.18 0 0 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <box>
          <size>0.2 0.2 0.2</size>
        </box>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <link name="front_left_wheel">
    <pose>0.2425 0.240 -0.05 0 0 1.57</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>1</mass>
    <inertia>
      <ixx>0.006292</ixx>
      <ixy>0</ixy>
      <ixz>0</ixz>
      <iyy>0.0039638</iyy>
      <iyz>0</iyz>
      <izz>0.0039638</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>

    <visual name="visual">
      <pose>0.04 0.0 0.0 0 0 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://prius_hybrid/meshes/Hybrid.obj</uri>
          <scale>0.003 0.003 0.003</scale>
          <submesh>
            <name>Wheel_Front_Left_</name>
            <center>true</center>
          </submesh>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision name="collision">
      <pose>0.0 0.0 0.0 0 1.5707963267948966 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>0.1</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>0.9</mu>
            <mu2>0.9</mu2>
        <slip1>0.0</slip1>
            <slip2>0.0</slip2>
          </ode>
        </friction>
        <contact>
          <ode>
            <min_depth>0.001</min_depth>
            <kp>1e9</kp>
          </ode>
        </contact>
      </surface>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <link name="front_right_wheel">
    <pose>0.2425 -0.240 -0.05 0 0 1.57</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>1</mass>
    <inertia>
      <ixx>0.006292</ixx>
      <ixy>0</ixy>
      <ixz>0</ixz>
      <iyy>0.0039638</iyy>
      <iyz>0</iyz>
      <izz>0.0039638</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>
    <visual name="visual">
      <pose>-0.04 0.0 0.0 0 0 0</pose>
      <pose>0 0 0.0 0 0 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://prius_hybrid/meshes/Hybrid.obj</uri>
          <scale>0.003 0.003 0.003</scale>
          <submesh>
            <name>Wheel_Front_Right</name>
            <center>true</center>
          </submesh>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision name="collision">
      <pose>0.0 0.0 0.0 0 1.5707963267948966 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>0.1</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>0.9</mu>
            <mu2>0.9</mu2>
            <slip1>0.0</slip1>
            <slip2>0.0</slip2>
          </ode>
        </friction>
        <contact>
          <ode>
            <min_depth>0.001</min_depth>
            <kp>1e9</kp>
          </ode>
        </contact>
      </surface>
    </collision>
  </link>


  <link name="rear_left_wheel">
    <pose>-0.2425 0.240 -0.05 0 0 1.57</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>1</mass>
    <inertia>
      <ixx>0.006292</ixx>
      <ixy>0</ixy>
      <ixz>0</ixz>
      <iyy>0.0039638</iyy>
      <iyz>0</iyz>
      <izz>0.0039638</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>

    <visual name="visual">
      <pose>0.04 0.0 0.0 0 0 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://prius_hybrid/meshes/Hybrid.obj</uri>
          <scale>0.003 0.003 0.003</scale>
          <submesh>
            <name>Wheel_Front_Left_</name>
            <center>true</center>
          </submesh>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision name="collision">
      <pose>0.0 0.0 0.0 0 1.5707963267948966 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>0.1</radius>
        </sphere>
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>1.1</mu>
            <mu2>1.1</mu2>
        <slip1>0.0</slip1>
            <slip2>0.0</slip2>
          </ode>
        </friction>
        <contact>
          <ode>
            <min_depth>0.001</min_depth>
            <kp>1e9</kp>
          </ode>
        </contact>
      </surface>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <link name="rear_right_wheel">
    <pose>-0.2425 -0.240 -0.05 0 0 1.57</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>1</mass>
    <inertia>
      <ixx>0.006292</ixx>
      <ixy>0</ixy>
      <ixz>0</ixz>
      <iyy>0.0039638</iyy>
      <iyz>0</iyz>
      <izz>0.0039638</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>
    <visual name="visual">
      <pose>-0.04 0.0 0.0 0 0 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <mesh>
          <uri>model://prius_hybrid/meshes/Hybrid.obj</uri>
          <scale>0.003 0.003 0.003</scale>
          <submesh>
            <name>Wheel_Front_Right</name>
            <center>true</center>
          </submesh>
        </mesh>
      </geometry>
    </visual>

    <collision name="collision">
      <pose>0.0 0.0 0.0 0 1.5707963267948966 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <sphere>
          <radius>0.1</radius>
        </sphere>0
      </geometry>
      <surface>
        <friction>
          <ode>
            <mu>1.1</mu>
            <mu2>1.1</mu2>
        <slip1>0.0</slip1>
            <slip2>0.0</slip2>
          </ode>
        </friction>
        <contact>
          <ode>
            <min_depth>0.001</min_depth>
            <kp>1e9</kp>
          </ode>
        </contact>
      </surface>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <joint type="universal" name="front_left_combined_joint">
    <pose>0 0 0 -0.08726646259971647 0 0</pose>
    <child>front_left_wheel</child>
    <parent>chassis</parent>
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
      <limit>
        <!-- +- 50 degrees -->
        <lower>-0.8727</lower>
        <upper>0.8727</upper>
      </limit>
      <dynamics>
        <friction>1</friction>
      </dynamics>
    </axis>
    <axis2>
      <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
      <dynamics>
        <friction>0.0001</friction>
      </dynamics>
    </axis2>
  </joint>

  <joint type="universal" name="front_right_combined_joint">
    <pose>0 0 0 -0.08726646259971647 0 0</pose>
    <child>front_right_wheel</child>
    <parent>chassis</parent>
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 0 1</xyz>
      <limit>
        <!-- +- 50 degrees -->
        <lower>-0.8727</lower>
        <upper>0.8727</upper>
      </limit>
      <dynamics>
        <friction>1</friction>
      </dynamics>
    </axis>
    <axis2>
      <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
      <dynamics>
        <friction>0.0001</friction>
      </dynamics>
    </axis2>
  </joint>

  <!--<link name="rear_axle">
  <pose>0 -0.25 0.3 0 0 0</pose>
    <inertial>
      <mass>0.5</mass>
      <inertia>
        <ixx>0.00000225</ixx>
        <ixy>0.0</ixy>
        <iyy>0.00371125</iyy>
        <ixz>0.0</ixz>
        <iyz>0.0</iyz>
        <izz>0.00371125</izz>
      </inertia>
    </inertial>
    <visual name="visual">
      <pose>0.0 0.0 0.0 0 1.5707963267948966 0</pose>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder>
          <length>0.3</length>
          <radius>0.003</radius>
        </cylinder>
      </geometry>
      <material>
        <script>
          <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
          <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
        </script>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint type="revolute" name="rear_axle_joint">
    <parent>chassis</parent>    
    <child>rear_axle</child>        
    <axis>
      <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
      <limit>
        <lower>-0.05089058524173028</lower>
        <upper>0.05089058524173028</upper>
      </limit>
      <dynamics>
        <spring_stiffness>20000.0</spring_stiffness>
        <damping>2000.0</damping>
      </dynamics>
    </axis>
  </joint>-->

  <joint type="revolute" name="rear_left_wheel_joint">
    <child>rear_left_wheel</child>
    <parent>chassis</parent>
    <axis>
      <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
      <dynamics>
        <friction>10</friction>
      </dynamics>
    </axis>
  </joint>
  <joint type="revolute" name="rear_right_wheel_joint">
    <child>rear_right_wheel</child>
    <parent>chassis</parent>
    <axis>
      <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
      <dynamics>
        <friction>10</friction>
      </dynamics>
    </axis>
  </joint>

  <joint name="steering_joint" type="revolute">
    <pose>-0.002 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
    <parent>chassis</parent>
    <child>steering_wheel</child>
    <axis>
      <xyz>-0.964118 0.000768 0.265556</xyz>
      <limit>
        <lower>-7.85</lower>
        <upper>7.85</upper>
      </limit>
      <dynamics>
        <damping>1.0</damping>
      </dynamics>
      <use_parent_model_frame>true</use_parent_model_frame>
    </axis>
    <physics>
      <ode>
        <cfm_damping>1</cfm_damping>
      </ode>
    </physics>
  </joint>

  <joint name="chassis_torre" type="fixed">
    <pose>-0.1 0 0.03 0 0 0</pose>
    <parent>chassis</parent>
    <child>torre</child>
  </joint>

  <plugin name='ackermann_drive' filename='libgazebo_ros_ackermann_drive.so'>

    <!--<ros>
      <namespace>demo</namespace>
      <remapping>cmd_vel:=cmd_demo</remapping>
      <remapping>odom:=odom_demo</remapping>
      <remapping>distance:=distance_demo</remapping>
    </ros>-->

    <update_rate>10.0</update_rate>

    <!-- wheels -->
    <front_left_joint>front_left_combined_joint</front_left_joint>
    <front_right_joint>front_right_combined_joint</front_right_joint>
    <rear_left_joint>rear_left_wheel_joint</rear_left_joint>
    <rear_right_joint>rear_right_wheel_joint</rear_right_joint>
    <left_steering_joint>front_left_combined_joint</left_steering_joint>
    <right_steering_joint>front_right_combined_joint</right_steering_joint>
    <steering_wheel_joint>steering_joint</steering_wheel_joint>

    <!-- Max absolute steer angle for tyre in radians-->
    <!-- Any cmd_vel angular z greater than this would be capped -->
    <max_steer>0.6458</max_steer>

    <!-- Max absolute steering angle of steering wheel -->
    <max_steering_angle>7.85</max_steering_angle>

    <!-- Max absolute linear speed in m/s -->
    <max_speed>6</max_speed>

    <!-- PID tuning -->
    <left_steering_pid_gain>200 0 1</left_steering_pid_gain>
    <left_steering_i_range>0 0</left_steering_i_range>
    <right_steering_pid_gain>200 0 1</right_steering_pid_gain>
    <right_steering_i_range>0 0</right_steering_i_range>
    <linear_velocity_pid_gain>92 0 1</linear_velocity_pid_gain>
    <linear_velocity_i_range>0 0</linear_velocity_i_range>

    <!-- output -->
    <publish_odom>true</publish_odom>
    <publish_odom_tf>true</publish_odom_tf>
    <publish_wheel_tf>true</publish_wheel_tf>
    <publish_distance>true</publish_distance>

    <odometry_frame>odom</odometry_frame>
    <robot_base_frame>chassis</robot_base_frame>

  </plugin>
</model>
```

Thank you!

Dani.

Comment: hey, did you find any solution?